# Why use poll() instead of take() in zookeeper WorkerSender

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I have been reading zookeeper source code and found that when fetching `ToSend` message from the queue in `FastLeaderElection.WorkerSender`, they use `poll()` instead of `take()`. Why?

Is `poll()` better?

Searching the git history, I've found that it started using `take()`, so there must have been a reason for changing to `poll()`.

```java
public void run() {
  while (!stop) {
    try {
      ToSend m = sendqueue.poll(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      if (m == null) {
        continue;
      }
      process(m);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      break;
    }
  }
  LOG.info("WorkerSender is down");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TL;DR:* To check the stop flag.

---

Change made for [ZOOKEEPER-498](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-498): Diff of [`FastLeaderElection.java`](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/zookeeper/trunk/src/java/main/org/apache/zookeeper/server/quorum/FastLeaderElection.java?r1=803300&r2=803299&pathrev=803300)

Old code:

```
class WorkerReceiver implements Runnable {

    QuorumCnxManager manager;

    WorkerReceiver(QuorumCnxManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public void run() {

        Message response;
        while (true) {
            // Sleeps on receive
            try{
                response = manager.recvQueue.take();

                // Receive new message
                LOG.debug("Receive new message.");
```

New code:

```
class WorkerReceiver implements Runnable {
    volatile boolean stop;
    QuorumCnxManager manager;

    WorkerReceiver(QuorumCnxManager manager) {
        this.stop = false;
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public void run() {

        Message response;
        while (!stop) {
            // Sleeps on receive
            try{
                response = manager.recvQueue.poll(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                if(response == null) continue;

                // Receive new message
                LOG.debug("Receive new message.");
```

> they use `poll()` instead of `take()`. Why ?

So they can check the **new `stop` flag** every 3 seconds.